# Stereotype in UML

Tags: terminology, modelling, software-engineering, object-oriented

What is a Stereotype in Unified modelling language?And What are the primary class stereotypes?.I need clear explanation using diagrams or real world scenario.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=stereotype+um

Comment: Actually i searched it in google. There are some issues. There is no proper article in wikipedia for that. And  some websites define it related MVC architecture. But wikipedia define it in  another way. what is the correct one?. If MVC is the correct one, Only those (boundry,controller,model) are the stereotypes in UML?. And what are the primary class stereotypes. This was a question which i got in the  software engineering paper paper at the University.

Comment: It's often helpful to tell us in the question what research you've done, what resources you found, and why you rejected them or why they didn't help.  Why were standard resources unhelpful or insufficient in this case?  It's great to answer your own question, but the question should be of reasonable quality too.  See also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183847/160917, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256654/160917, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137369/160917.

Answer (score 0):

A stereotype is a mechanism you can use to categorize your classes. You can create new stereotypes and categorize as you like

For example:

> Think if you want to simply find all of the forms in the model. In
>   that case you can create a stereotype called form and assign all of
>   your view classes which consists with a form, this stereotype. To find your
>   forms later You would just need to look for the classes with that
>   stereotype.

There are three primary class stereotype in UML.

1. Boundry class
2. Entity class
3. control class

**Boundary class**

They provide the interface to a user or another System(ie. Interface to an actor)

**Entity class**

They are needed to perform task internal to the system, reflect a real world entity.

**Control class**

Serve as the glue between boundary elements and entity elements, implementing the logic required to manage the various elements and their interactions.